# Android turn gps on using NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gps

I would like to ask about something. I'm now aware that there's no possibility to turn GPS on via normal SDK application. My problem is that I need to do it without user's confirmation (my application's fundamental is to work silently). I need it because my application is meant to be used by a company to track their devices (tablets). It needs to turn on GPS to obtain location and after that turn it off. That means, if we prompt user to turn GPS on, he may not do it and the application (a service actually) will not work properly.

My next step is to find an alternative solution, I mean, if we turn GPS on using settings, it eventually gets turned on by a core application/service. My assumption is that it uses native code to access the GPS device and turn it on (if I'm wrong, please correct me and point to the right answer).

Therefore my question is - if possible, how can I do that in NDK and later on how to integrate it with my application. If NDK can't handle it, how it can be done? There must be a way, since it's eventually done in settings.

I would also like to ask the same question about Internet connection (to alternatively use network provider to obtain location).

Thanks in advance for any contribution!

Comment: "My assumption is that it uses native code to access the GPS device and turn it on" -- yes, with specific permissions in place that prevent you from modifying this setting from your process.

Comment: Alright, so the next question that appears is - is there any way to manage those permissions to give my process this permission? What are requirements for the application to have those permissions?

Comment: "What are requirements for the application to have those permissions?" -- at best, you might be able to root the device and install your app on the system partition. At worst, you roll your own ROM mod, install that on the device, and sign your app with the signing key you used when signing the firmware in the ROM mod.

Comment: The second solution seems more convinient. If we root the device, user can control what access superuser rights - he can block the app. Is there anything more I can find about ROM mods? Can it be installed on working system or there is a need to install whole custom build of Android? And well, isn't the ROM device-dependent?

Comment: "Is there anything more I can find about ROM mods?" -- lots, but that's generally beyond the scope of StackOverflow. "there is a need to install whole custom build of Android" -- absolutely. That is the definition of a ROM mod; you are replacing the entire device firmware with your own, losing all original capabilities and replacing them with your own. "And well, isn't the ROM device-dependent?" -- yes, very.

Comment: I think that's enough information for me, If You should post it as an answer so I can mark the question answered. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The NDK does not give you an end-run around the Android permission model, as permissions are enforced either at the other side of an interprocess call, or in the kernel - in both cases meaning in code belonging to the platform, which you cannot as a 3rd party developer modify.  In many cases, the NDK actually gives you *less* platform-interaction capability than Java, as many of the Android APIs have their client-side glue code written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You might find a way to handle GPS with NDK/JNI calls, but there's no such thing as GPS without notice to the user on an Android device. He can switch GPS off or refuse to switch it on. In such a case, that device itself (the hardware) switches the GPS sensor off.

What might be possible is to use other ways to locate the device:

- Wifi gives you the position not as accurate as GPS, but better then nothing
- Carrier track the position of a device according to the signal strength arriving at their antennas. But I haven't seen any Android interface able to handle that (might be a question to  ask here, if anybody knows how to get that information)
- The way, I'd handle your problem is on the organizational side (as this is company internal stuff): You basically say to the user: "Switch on GPS and you, user, get access to your emails" (well, as an example)
  Give something and you will get something back :-)

Comment: You cannot enable the network provider, any more than you can enable the GPS provider.

Comment: Well, nothing that I wouldn't know of already. The problem with WiFi is exactly the same, it needs user to turn it on (or am I wrong?). Ye, carrier does track it, but I see no reason for them to share this information with others. Third possibility is not a possibility at all, I can't imagine telling this company to force their employees to keep GPS on, also that is a power issue to keep it on all the time. They don't want employees to use devices for personal stuff, what if an employee say he turned it off accidentally?

Comment: For me that looks like there's is the need to rethink or rediscuss the requirements. I dont see a technical way to switch GPS on without notice and allowance of the user. Also you do not see a way thru company policies. At third, keeping GPS on is a power consumption issue (which it is anyway regardless of how you switch it on). In the answer, the third alternative should lead into thinking in the non-technical direction as I do not see a proper technical solution.

Answer (score 0):

"Settings" is not an application to begin with.

So if you already made an application you should understand somehow the basics of Android applications but if you didn't really understand them then I'd like to say that the applications generally run in a "sandbox" and these applications may be destroyed / terminated by the system should it deem it necessary. There's also no such thing as "silent mode" either. The user MUST ACCEPT / DECLINE permissions and the user MUST be in control of his device should you have the Android OS installed on your devices.
There are ways to circumvent that of course and those ways may be ranging from:

1. Make all devices have one central account on Google Play and activate the service to erase / destroy the device if they get lost, (You can find that in settings since you mentioned it ... under administrator accounts) and leave things right there as they are since that's all you need at the end of the day.
2. (Requires 1 to be enabled) You should make all your corporate devices (if you want to be that kind of jailer but going that path will make your employees just see you as a not so great employer) to run your piece of software and every single thing that needs access to your network will be running on a proprietary custom encrypted channel (no public encryption) and with the usage of the administrator account you being able to control what the users can install on their devices you can restrict that the only application is that said application that was mentioned above. Now make all that your employees need as a subapplication of your application ;) and on top of that enable these applications to be able to run ONLY if there's GPS signal (so if your employee gets in the tube ... his device will stop working) add / subtract whatever you feel right from this.
3. Be a good employer and just leave them do whatever they please with the devices you gave them. If you give trust you'll receive joy for the work they're doing meanwhile if you jail people you receive negative emotions and bad performance (eventually it can even go in the direction that people will just leave for a better employer)

From all the 3 I would certain go for the third option if I were in your shoes. From a technology challenge the #2 is I think the only way and a very interesting architecture that you could implement ... in a long time ... so you also need to make sure the effort invested in this is worth the 2 hours your employer will play angry birds at home with his child ;) nevertheless if you're in it for the challenge more than any real world application this is a great chance for you to learn the android operating system from all its perspectives. NDK may help you here but not the way you want it... more along the lines of custom encryption and so on.

EDIT: Sorry for my twisted logic and way of expressing but it's pretty late and has been a very long day.